# classic asp string to display only results beginning with a certain letter

Tags: sql

Time for problem #2!

I would like to display only those records in the database with a certain field beginning with a specific letter.

The connection string I normally use to display records is:

```
strSQL = "SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Reviews ORDER BY Artist DESC"
```

How do I change this to only display records where the Artist field in the db starts with (for example) the letter A?

Can it be done?

Thanks once again,

Ian

Comment: I kindly but strongly suggest you review standard SQL syntax; this is fairly straightforward.  Also, pedantic:  that's a query, not a connection string.

Comment: That shows how little I know when it comes to classic asp, which is why I am asking for help!  I don't even know where to start looking :(

Comment: Please edit your question.  Drop the asp-classic tag.  Add SQL tag, and preferably add the tag for the DB that you are using.  These are important things if you are going to continue using SO, AND get the most out of coming here.  It's a great resource.

Comment: @IanWilliams - I would start with [Writing SQL Queries: Let's Start with the Basics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264565(v=sql.90).aspx).  It's got some good examples of a number of basic queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this isn't a classic ASP question, it is a SQL question.  Second, that's not a connection string...

Anyway, the solution will depend on your DB as there can be slight variations in the way SQL is implemented by different systems.

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Reviews WHERE Artist LIKE 'A%' ORDER BY Artist DESC
```